# How to save dynamic key value pairs in Java?

Tags: java, collections

I want to save a value of few 'flags' into one variable.

For eg. There are 2 integer flag xdirection = 0 , ydirection = 1

Now these values can change during the execution of program.

I have tried ArrayList and HashMap but they only store the values at the very moment the value is added to the maps.

Basically what I want is a list of maps giving me 2 things, 1 - The name of the variable (I can hardcode it while putting it in the map) and 2 - the integer value of this variable/flag currently in the program.

Comment: `I have tried [...] HashMap` can you show your attempt? Sounds like a Map is exactly what you need

Comment: yes..plz show us some code snippet

Comment: If u create a new object with two integers xdirection and ydirection both of them static

Comment: no, `static` is bad um k ...

Comment: He said "Now these values can change during the execution of program." but only want a single object on the program, so is the only way

Comment: `static` primitives is the **worst** way but **not** the **only** way. and regardless of what the OP seems to want, **never** suggest *worst practices* especially to those that are new players.

Answer (score 2):

#### Why will a normal object not work?

> The question reeks of the **global state machine anti-pattern** and
>   this answer should be taken with that in mind. `Singletons` that are
>   **not** finite external resources like socket or file references are bad for many well documented reasons that are easy to find on the
>   internet in general so I will not touch on that here. You should seriously avoid these types of naive state machines.

```
public final class Direction
{
   public final AtomicInteger xDirection;
   public final AtomicInteger yDirection;

   public final Direction(final int x, final int y) 
   {  
      this.xDirection = new AtomicInteger(x);
      this.yDirection = new AtomicInteger(y);
   }
}
```

That said, `int` is probably the **wrong** type, the term `flag` implies that you should be using `Boolean` given the limited information in your question.

```
public final class Direction
{
   public final AtomicBoolean isXdirection;
   public final Atomicboolean isYdirection;

   public final Direction(final boolean x, final boolean y) 
   {  
      this.xDirection = new AtomicBoolean(x);
      this.yDirection = new AtomicBoolean(y);
   }
}
```

This also has the benefit of being *thread safe* as well as the `final` references are immutable and the `AtomicInteger/Boolean` are as well.

> Resist the desire to create a pseudo-global reference, it should be on
>   an a single instance of an object that is passed around to all the
>   places that need to read the current state.